# Receiving empty object from Ajax post request

Tags: php, ajax, post, symfony

I'll try to explain my problem.  I have an entity which is joined with two other entities with many to many relationship.  What I want to achieve is to search with ajax post method, and receive all the possible combinations that are connected in the joined tables.

My real problem is that I receive valid callback data only if only I search in the first entity.

The controller:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {


       $name = $request->request->get('person_name');
       /** @var EntityRepository $repository */
       $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Connectors');
       $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('connectors')
           ->leftJoin('connectors.contacts', 'contacts')
           ->leftJoin('contacts.cables', 'cables');

       $qb->where('connectors.description LIKE :param');
       $qb->setParameter('param','%'.$name.'%');

       $connectors = [];
       $contacts = [];
       $cables = [];

       foreach ($qb->getQuery()->getResult() as $connector) {
           $connectors[] = $connector;
           foreach ($connector->getContacts() as $contact) {
               $contacts[] = $contact;
               foreach ($contact->getCable() as $cable) {
                   $cables[] = $cable;
               }
           }
       }

      // $Data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
       return new JsonResponse(json_encode($contacts));
   }
```

At this point I want to send the $contacts array I receive is empty ( NULL ), but more interestingly [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}] the amount of curly brackets is same amount of contacts that I'm suppose to receive!!

And if the commented line is un-commented and $Data is send as response there are no issues.

The JS

```
$('#call_back_btn' ).click(function() {
                 $.post("/app_dev.php/AjaxSearch" ,
                     {
                     person_name:$('#input_text').val()
                     } ,
                     function (data)
                     {
                         console.log(data);
                          var obj =  JSON.parse(data);
                         console.log(obj);

                         // for (var key in data)
                         // {
                         //     if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                         //         console.log(data);
                         //     }
                         // }

                     $('#resposeText').val(obj[1].description);

                     }
                 );
             })
            }
        );
```

I would appreciate your help

Here is my console output:

[image]

Comment: You have to echo out the data you wants to return.@Metio_1993

Comment: Even if I echo the data, nothing happens

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Yes, I have included the jQuery library, no there are no errors,  Yeah I watch the all responses on the browser, I can see that I have a post request and response, but as I mentioned I have nothing!

Comment: No one can answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to find where the mistake was.

The format was the trouble, So I installed JMSSerializerBundle  and then converted the data to JSON

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
    $reports = $serializer->serialize($cables, 'json');
    $reports1 = $serializer->serialize($contacts, 'json');
    return new JsonResponse (array($reports1, $reports));
```